# Equivalent of NUnit or Jasmine assertions for Python?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Using **Python** unittest I found myself missing the clean descriptive ways of writing unit tests assertions like done in **NUnit** or **Jasmine**:

```
# NUnit
Expect(collection, Has.None.EqualTo(DateTime.Now).Within(3).Hours);

# Jasmine
expect(pi).not.toBeCloseTo(e, 2);
```

Is there an existing Python library providing such assertion methods, preferably compatible with Python's [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) library?

Answer (score 0):

How about [PyHamcrest](https://github.com/hamcrest/PyHamcrest) ?

```
assert_that(biscuit, equal_to(biscuit))
assert_that(biscuit, instance_of(Biscuit))
assert_that(biscuit, is_in(jar))
```

more matchers: https://github.com/hamcrest/PyHamcrest#predefined-matchers